# Element not removed from the list

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote the code below. I'm reading a file and removing the element from the first index, but it's not removing. Can someone help?

```
import os
fo = open('temp_file.txt', 'w')
fo.write(output1)
fo.close()   
fo = open('temp_file.txt', 'r')
temp_list = fo.readlines()
fo.close()
os.remove('temp_file.txt')
del temp_list[0]
print (temp_list)
```

Comment: What exactly is not removing? os.remove('temp_file.txt')?  I ran your code, had to change fo.write(output1) to fo.write("test") since it was undefined.  My result was simply [] and the .txt was removed after run.  My suggest would be to make os.remove() a long path such as "C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\program\temp_file.txt"

Comment: I can't reproduce you problem using `"test1\ntest2\ntest3\n"` for `output1`.

Comment: del temp_list[0] is not removing the first element from the list.

Comment: output1 contains data as below:
Fri Jul  7 13:43:23.259 utc

Te0/0/0/0/0       down        down        LNGAMQ/|Preprod|

Te0/00/0/0/0    down        down        |Preprod|

Te0/10/0/0/0     down        down        |Preprod|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is the solution to your problem?

```
import os
fo = open('temp_file.txt', 'w')
fo.write("test\n")
fo.write("test2\n")
fo.write("test3\n")
fo.close()
fo = open('temp_file.txt', 'r')
temp_list = []
for i in fo.readlines():
    temp_list.append(i)
fo.close()
os.remove('temp_file.txt')
print(temp_list)
del temp_list[0]
print (temp_list)
```

Output:

```
['test\n', 'test2\n', 'test3\n']
['test2\n', 'test3\n']
```

Comment: yes, this way would work, But what was wrong in the original method, i generated the list there also. And no of lines were reduced.

Comment: To be honest @GoldyTomy I have no idea lol.  I think you might be able to reduce this to simply `del fo.readlines()[0]` Since fo.readlines() is creating it's own list.  When I did temp_list.append(fo.readlines()) it actually made a list with the nested fo.readlines() list inside of it.  Sec, I'll see if it works and update you.  EDIT: disregard, `fo.readlines()[0]` isn't valid. Hmm.  I'm not too sure why you can't easily translate `fo.readlines()` into a list via the `=` method.

Comment: str = fo.readline();
while str:;
         temp_list = str;
         str = fo.readline();



This would generate only one list. But readlines does all the work in one line

Comment: After re-running I found that I can run this fine without any real issue.  `temp_list = fo.readlines()` should be perfectly valid and turn temp_list into the same list from `fo.readlines()`.  I'm on python 3.6.1 if that makes any difference to you.  For now, I'd just bruteforce the list creation with a for loop.